# Is there a Dynamic Programming way to compute the k minimum spanning trees?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming, minimum-spanning-tree

My teacher asked us to implement a Dynamic Programming solution to that problem, but I'm thinking one doesn't exist since I couldn't find it using Google.

Anyway, given a graph and a k, say 3, you have to find the 3 best MSTs from it. If the graph is such that it doesn't have k subtrees, you can return either the same tree multiple times or suboptimal trees.

I can't really think of a solution to it.

Comment: trust me, there is no fun in knowing the answer. finding your own way through the answer is the real **fun**

Comment: @Gollum: Well said, +1 to your comment :-)

Comment: 'I'm thinking one doesn't exist since I couldn't find it using Google':  I remember someone twitting that that these are sad times, since googling has gotten faster than thinking.

Comment: There is such a solution using DP. have a look at: www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard

Comment: @Ofek my teacher is full of crazy ideas. I was looking for a solution because he's the kind to give us an assignment that hasn't been solved yet. I'm not gonna waste weeks trying to solve a problem even PhDs couldn't. In this situation though there seems to be a solution, even though I've yet to come across it.

Answer (score 3):

You had me confused for a while there and I thought you might have misunderstood the problem. The "k-MST" problem consists of finding k edges that form a subtree such that the sum of its edges is less than or equal to all other sums you can get from subtrees of k edges. But then I saw the plural s.

So ok, for your problem, I personally would try to find a DP-algorithm for finding the MST that combines with a way of generating a "next" MSTs. Since this is dynamic programming I'd look into repeatedly optimizing something (in this case de-optimizing for each step) or at various ways of partitioning edges into subsets that make sense in an MST setting. There might be several ways.

However, searching for partitions and minimum spanning trees I found this, which might be more of help if you just want the answer: http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0101-74382005000200004

Comment: What? A greedy algorithm is not a DP algorithm, and your answer is not at all helpful. He's asking **how** to find something, not **what** to find. -1.

Comment: I apologize, I shall remove the reference to greedy, it was another misunderstanding (I was still thinking about k-MST, where you'd select sub-searches in a greedy manner much like most MST generation). And yes, you are right, I did not give an explicit answer, just how I would think or approach it. (Since it's a homework problem.)

Comment: Clarified and added a link to actual solution.

Comment: Other links for that article that load faster: https://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S0101-74382005000200004 and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249927162_An_algorithm_to_generate_all_spanning_trees_of_a_graph_in_order_of_increasing_cost